# Google Maps Android v2 - How to add a hole circle in a polygon?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Does anyone know how to create a hole circle in a polygon with Google Maps Android V2?

Like this
https://www.dropbox.com/s/kksr3va2dm87o1q/print.png

I see only hole with array latlong, but I need a hole circle.

```
mMap.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions()
    .add(new LatLng(0, 0), new LatLng(0, 5), new LatLng(3, 5), new LatLng(3, 0), new LatLng(0, 0))
    .addHole(new LatLng(1, 1), new LatLng(1, 2), new LatLng(2, 2), new LatLng(2, 1), new LatLng(1, 1))
    .fillColor(Color.BLUE));
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Could you provide more context for your task and where you are adding this polygon? The question is tagged with `google-maps` tags but there's nothing stated about Google Maps API.

Comment: Sorry, I put "Google Maps Android v2" in the title. I thought was enough. I'm searching about any way to draw a polygon with a hole circle, in Google Maps Android V2. I try add a image in the topic, but I don't have minimum points for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Circle`s can't have holes. You can generate your own path that's a circle using the spherical functions in the [`android-maps-utils`](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils) project.

Specifically, use the [`SphericalUtil.computeOffset`](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/SphericalUtil.java) function.

It returns the LatLng resulting from moving a distance from an origin in the specified heading (expressed in degrees clockwise from north).